# Output elements of array depending by a condition

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects. I should loop through this array, to sort it and to output the title of each element only if the previous title is different by the previous.

```js
const arr = [
  {
    title:'First',
    age: 12
  },
    {
    title:'Second',
    age: 6
  },
    {
    title:'Third',
    age: 8
  },
    {
    title:'First',
    age: 5
  }
]
const sorted = arr.sort((a, b) => (a.title > b.title ? 1 : -1));
const mapArr = sorted.map((i,k) => {
  return{
    ...i,
    title: i.title !== i.title[k-1]
  }
})
console.log(mapArr)
```

Unfortunately the code is not working as i expect, and my target is to get this:

```js
[
  {
    title:'First',
    age: 12
  },
   {
    age: 5
  },
    {
    title:'Second',
    age: 6
  },
    {
    title:'Third',
    age: 8
  },  
]
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong. There is no `i.title[k-1]` property, there is `i.title`.

You can probably do something like this:

```js
const arr = [
      {
        title:'First',
        age: 12
      },
      {
        title:'Second',
        age: 6
      },
        {
        title:'Third',
        age: 8
      },
        {
        title:'First',
        age: 5
      }
    ]
    const sorted = arr.sort((a, b) => (a.title > b.title ? 1 : -1));
    const newArr = [];
    let k = sorted.length - 1;
    while (k > 0) {
      newArr.push({
        ...sorted[k],
        title: sorted[k].title !== sorted[k-1].title ? sorted[k].title : null
      })
      k--;
    }
    newArr.push(sorted[0])
    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(newArr)) {
      if (value.title === null) delete newArr[key].title;
    }
    console.log(newArr.reverse())
```

Comment: i need `null` not for the first item, but for the second.

Comment: @AskMen then reverse the for loop & finally reverse the array. check my edit, i did it for you :)